# Creating RGB color function, javascript error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create random colors using the following function in javascript, but getting this error: Syntax Error: expected expression, got ')'.  Can anyone tell me what this error message refers to?

function addEvents(){

```
$('table').mouseover(function(){

    var color = "rgb(";

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

        var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

        color += random;

        if (i<2){
            color += ",";

        } else {
            color += ")";
    };

    $(this).css('color', color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing an "}" in your code

```
if (i<2){
  color += ",";
} else {
  color += ")";
} // <--- THIS ONE IS MISSING
```

Usually your debugger will show you the line number the error occured at